# Calculate total amount per quantity enter in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

What is the correct formula to calculate the total per Quantity enter

> [image: PowerApps Form]

SharePoint List

> [image]

Comment: this link is helpful https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-Sum-of-Sharepoint-list-column-total-by-month/td-p/255363

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful,it provides details about the PowerApps formulas :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-formulas